# pass custom value from single.php to another file via get

Tags: custom-field

I have multi values that I would like to pass to another external php file which is not single php

```
_s_0_e_0_source1
_s_0_e_0_source2
_s_0_e_0_source3
```

I would like to use the method

`http://mywebsite.com/external.php?id=post_id&source1=_s_0_e_0_source1&source2=_s_0_e_0_source2&source3=_s_0_e_0_source3`

```php
$postid = $_GET['id'];
    
$source1 = get_post_meta($postid, $_GET['source1'], true); don't work
    
$source1 = get_post_meta($postid, '_s_0_e_0_source1', true); work
```

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the URL you have provided: `...source1=_s_0_e_0_source16source2=...`. It should most probably read `...source1=_s_0_e_0_source1&source2=...`.

Comment: i know it's just an example

Comment: Keep in mind there's a massive security hole in what you want to do, I could put any meta key I want into `source1` and it would use that instead, not just `_s_0_e_0_source1` but other meta keys that weren't intended